# Quicktime error in IE7 opening mp3, Icon with Questionmark

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, mp3, quicktime

I am having some Internet Explorer 7 (and 8 beta) browser-specific problems with a link to an MP3.

When I click the link in IE7, a new browser window opens and the quicktime plugin tries to play the file.  Instead ofthe player, I see a faded Quicktime icon with a question mark in the center.
[alt text http://img87.imageshack.us/img87/6871/quicktimeeh4.jpg](http://img87.imageshack.us/img87/6871/quicktimeeh4.jpg)

There is nothing wrong with the file.

The quicktime player opens and plays the file correctly in FireFox3, Safari and Chrome.

I have tried on several different computers using IE7 and it always fails.

I have searched other forums in vain to find a solution.  I have seen suggestions from changing registry settings to reinstalling IE (did not help).

This is the exact HTML that links the file :

```
<a onmouseover="window.status=''; return true;" target="_blank"name="Filename_Lnk" href="polka.mp3">
  Lawrence Welk
</a>
```

The webpage with the link and file both sit inside a website to which you must be logged in.

My only thought is that IE is somehow losing the session by opening the file in a new browser.  FF handles this fine.

I would love to be able to tell my users how to configure IE so that this file opens in Windows Media Player instead of Quicktime.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reconfigure the QuickTime's files associations in the Control Panel to make it *not* play the MP3 in your browser.

Of course, you could post a link instead, and have them download the file and then play it - it's more likely to work.

Finally, you could use a [Flash-based MP3 player](http://www.flashmp3player.org/demo.html), or re-encode the file and embed it in a Flash that would auto-play it.